# What is the Entity Framework equivalent of SQL UPDATE?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I looked all over the internet and still couldn't find a solution to this.

I tried the attach method:

```
    public static void updatePhoto(string name, string albumName, string newName, string newPath)
    {
        //updates photo... no delete and adding...
        var photo = new Image(){Label=newName, Path = newPath};
        using (var db = new EzPrintsEntities())
        {
            db.Images.Attach(photo);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

    }
```

but that did not do anything at all.

**So the question then is how do you implement an UPDATE to the sql database through EF in the code below?**

```
    public static void updatePhoto(string name, string albumName, string newName, string newPath)
    {
         EzPrintsEntities db = new EzPrintsEntities();

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're updating an existing photo, you need to load it, and change the existing value:

```
public static void updatePhoto(string name, string albumName, string newName, string newPath)
{
    using (var db = new EzPrintsEntities())
    {
        // Load photo
        var photo = db.Images.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Label == name && i.Album == albumName);
        if (photo == null)
        {
           // no matching photo - do something
        }

        // Update data
        photo.Label = newName;
        photo.Path = newPath; 

        db.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

Comment: What if you want to update several thousand records where a condition matches

Answer (score 0):

The simplist way would be:

```
public static void updatePhoto(string name, string albumName, string newName, string newPath)   
{   
    //updates photo... no delete and adding...       

    using (var db = new EzPrintsEntities())   
    {   
        var photo = (from p in db.Images
                 where p.name == name &&
                 p.albumname == albumName 
                 select p).First();
        photo.name = newName;
        photo.path = newPath;
        db.SaveChanges();   
    }   

}
```

You simply select the existing `photo` object using Linq, modify it, and `SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is also pass to your `updatePhoto` method the value(s) for the primary key on your `Image` entity.  Then instead of creating a new `Image` entity and attaching it and saving the context, you'll get the `Image` entity from your context, and just update the properties on it.

Something along these lines:

```
using (var db = new EzPrintsEntities())
{
    var image = db.Images.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == id); // Assuming Id is the PK on Image, and we sent in the PK in a variable called id.
    if (image != null)
    {
        image.Label = newName;
        image.Path = newPath;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        // Invalid PK value sent in, do something here (logging, error display, whatever).
    }
}
```